# Criar coluna no R a partir do número de registros por 2 IDs

Tags: r, data.frame

Estou iniciando no R e no stackflow. Solicito a ajuda de vocês. Tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```
library(lubridate)

ID = c("000225", "000225", "000225", "000225", "000226", "000226", "000227", "000227", "000227", "000227", "000225", "000225", "000225", "000225", "000226", "000226", "000227", "000227", "000227", "000227")
Hr = c("08:00","12:00","13:00" ,"17:00", "13:00" ,"17:00","08:00","12:00","13:00" ,"17:00",
       "08:00","12:00","13:00" ,"17:00", "13:00" ,"17:00","08:00","12:00","13:00" ,"17:00")
data =dmy(c("12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "12-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020", "13-11-2020"))

dados = data.frame(ID, Hr, data)
dados
```

As três primeiras colunas contêm os registros de ponto de colaboradores de uma empresa. O que eu preciso é gerar uma quarta coluna que identifique o tipo do registro:

```
       ID    Hr       data   tipo
1  000225 08:00 2020-11-12 início
2  000225 12:00 2020-11-12 almoço
3  000225 13:00 2020-11-12  volta
4  000225 17:00 2020-11-12  saída
5  000226 13:00 2020-11-12 início
6  000226 17:00 2020-11-12 almoço
7  000227 08:00 2020-11-12 início
8  000227 12:00 2020-11-12 almoço
9  000227 13:00 2020-11-12  volta
10 000227 17:00 2020-11-12  saída
11 000225 08:00 2020-11-13 início
12 000225 12:00 2020-11-13 almoço
13 000225 13:00 2020-11-13  volta
14 000225 17:00 2020-11-13  saída
15 000226 13:00 2020-11-13 início
16 000226 17:00 2020-11-13 almoço
17 000227 08:00 2020-11-13 início
18 000227 12:00 2020-11-13 almoço
19 000227 13:00 2020-11-13  volta
20 000227 17:00 2020-11-13  saída
```

Embora eu tenha criado estes dados para ilustrar, o BD onde irei coletar os dados obriga o usuário a registrar os horários na sequência: "início, almoço, volta, saída". Desse modo, num primeiro momento, não preciso ordenar os horários para um colaborador dentro daquele dia, pois o banco já fornece os dados nessa ordem.

Então, o que preciso é: quando o colaborador tenha apenas 1 registro no dia, identificar como "início". Se ele tiver 2 registros, identificar o primeiro como "início" e o segundo como "almoço". Se 3 registros, "início", "almoço" e "volta", etc. Conto com a ajuda de vocês. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução: numerar as linhas por categoria e converter os números para os tipos. Os pacotes `dplyr` e `data.table` facilitam a operação por categorias.  A conversão pode ser feita com um dicionário.

```
# Dicionário
tipos <- setNames(c("inicio", "almoco", "volta", "saida"), 1:4)
```

*Com dplyr*

```
library(dplyr)

dados %<>% group_by(ID, data) %>%
           mutate(tipo = tipos[1:n()])
```

*Com data.table*

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados)

dados[, tipo := tipos[1:.N], .(ID, data)]
```

Em ambos os casos, o resultado é o mesmo:

```
> head(dados, 10)
        ID    Hr       data   tipo
 1: 000225 08:00 2020-11-12 inicio
 2: 000225 12:00 2020-11-12 almoco
 3: 000225 13:00 2020-11-12  volta
 4: 000225 17:00 2020-11-12  saida
 5: 000226 13:00 2020-11-12 inicio
 6: 000226 17:00 2020-11-12 almoco
 7: 000227 08:00 2020-11-12 inicio
 8: 000227 12:00 2020-11-12 almoco
 9: 000227 13:00 2020-11-12  volta
10: 000227 17:00 2020-11-12  saida
```

Comment: Carlos, agradeço demais pela ajuda. Eu havia pesquisado como fazer isso e não havia encontrado uma solução. Sua resposta, além de servir como solução, foi um aprendizado, pois aprendi a agrupar no R, isso vai facilitar demais minha vida. Estou começando agora e achando o R incrível, mas um pouco difícil pra aprender. Vou me esforçar cada vez mais. Novamente, obrigado pela ajuda!